# How do I determine an image loaded successfully from a URI in Silverlight 2.0 (RC0)?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight-2.0

In the following code below:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://someURL/somefilename.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

how can I determine if the image successfully loaded (when there's a valid URI)? i.e., The URI is a valid format, but the file may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`Image` has an `ImageFailed` event.

`BitmapSource` (base for `BitmapImage`) has an `IsDownloading` property, as well as `DownloadProgress`, `DownloadCompleted`, and `DownloadFailed` events.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your example code above (with a valid url but invalid image file) you will get an exception thrown:

```
Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: ImageError error #4001 in control 'Xaml1': AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR
```

So if you wrap your code in a try/catch block you can determine if the image loaded property or not.

Comment: Actually, there is no exception thrown. I can link to garbage or to nothing at all and there is no exception.